# Redirection with special characters in the destination URL

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost

I have what I thought was a very straightforward URL redirection scenario. Visit a simple easy-to-remember mydomain URL and be redirected to the very complicated cloud address.

This is what I have inside an apache2 virtual host.

```
ServerName clock.mydomain.com   
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ https://sub.example.com/service/#/12345/login/webclock/1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

The issue is the `#` in the destination URL. The `#` is being html encoded as `%23` so the browser is looking and not finding `https://sub.example.com/service/%23/12345/login/webclock/1`

How can I fix this? Everything I am reading is about dealing with special characters in the origin URL, not the destination URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the mod_rewrite documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) you need to use the `NE` (no escape) flag when your rewrite rule has a hash.

```sh
ServerName clock.mydomain.com   
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ https://sub.example.com/service/#/12345/login/webclock/1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```